# jQuery: remove original space of draggable while dragging?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create my own draggable/sortable with jQuery (just for fun, so I'm not interested in doing this with the default jQuery sortable(), but I *do* use draggable()).

When I drag an element and hover it over another, I want the *original* space of the element to disappear.

Related to this, I can't understand that after dragging, all other elements stay in the *same place*. How does jQuery do that, because normally the space of the element that is moved, should be occupied with the elements below that one, right?

Is there some way to manually remove the 'original space' while dragging?

**UPDATE**

I just found out that draggable() makes the elements positioned '*relative*', which is why they stay in the same position after dragging... but the question remains how to reclaim the 'original' space then...

Comment: `reclaim` ---> `remove` ??

Comment: well, I meant remove the space of the element that is being dragged to reclaim it so the other elements move to that space...

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dragEl").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $("#toDisappear").fadeOut(3000); // or .hide();
    },
});
```

Means on `drag` `start` of `#dragEl`, make the `#toDisappear` `fadeOut` in `3000ms`.

[More info here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)

Comment: This does not answer the question.